# How to remove white pixels

Tags: pixel

Is there a way I can remove the white pixels(dots) from this image?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvIVs.jpg

Comment: What program do you intend to use? Many raster editing programs can edit the image using a cloning brush to remove the white dots.

Comment: What have you tried so far? And to add to AndrewH question: if you have access to something like Photoshop or GIMP, how familiar are you with using the tool?

Answer (score 2):

Photo editing programs have spot cleaning or "healing" brushes - only click over a dot and the program stretches the environment over the dot with no visible seam. As already suggested you can also use clone brush to copy same colored stuff from another place of the same image if good place where to take from exists.

There's semiautomatic healing brushes. You select where a patch will be taken from and the tool adjust the color of the patch to fit seamlessly with the environment. At least Photoshop has it and it is my favourite when defects hide some details which can be copied from elsewhere but the light condition must be adjusted.

Then there's dust and scratch removal filters. Their quality vary. Here's a half of the image fixed automatically with one.

[image]

The selection marquee area in the left is fixed with about 20 years old free "Polaroid Dust&Scratch Removal". It took only few seconds because the default settings were nearly optimal.

For a comparison the right side is fixed with the healing brush. It took about 100 clicks:

[image]

Polaroid's filter can be run as stand alone and as extension plugin for legacy 32bit Photoshop. That plugin fits into many programs which can use Photoshop plugins. I guess it can be still found somewhere, but I do not know where.

Comment: just my opinion... answering horrible, no-effort, no detail, questions only encourages more of the same.

Comment: fortunately he didn't get full fixed ready to use photo.

Comment: No.. but for minimal effort you've provided solutions. That, to me, encourages low quality questions. Basically.. providing *solutions* merely means there's no reason anyone need make any attempt or effort on their own. All they need do is post one sentence and a link and they get an answer.  **Most**, if not *all*, regular users here *could* answer this.. there's reason why *most* don't.

Comment: OK. Now the questioner knows there's such things as Photoshop and brushes. It's now possible he asks also something less exasperating about how to use them. The questioner has already shown in other Stack Exchange sites that he has also something to say at least of software, not only ask.

Comment: @user287001 do you mind sending me a copy of the image without the white spots? Would highly appreciate it!

Comment: OK. Here's a version where every noise dot is fixed. Nothing else is included. https://www.dropbox.com/s/82wyqu5nm0fvh4k/Patches.png?dl=0